# Does overflow occur in any of these cases?

Tags: binary, integer-overflow, twos-complement

Using `6-bit` two's complement arithmetic, does overflow occur in any of these cases? I believe there is a carry in question `b`, but no overflow.

```
(a) 11001 + 01000
(b) 10111 – 00110
(c) 00111 + 01100
(d) 10110 + 00011
```

The reason I say that `b` is an example of carry and not overflow is because the result is the same sign of the two numbers being added, even though there is a carry bit.

Comment: Do you mean 5-bit or 6-bit arithmetic? because you say `6-bit` in the question but your examples are 5-bits making them all positive numbers

Comment: I mean 6. When you want to increase bit length in twos complement , you move the sign bit to leftmost position and fill in with copies of the sign bit. For positive numbers,fill in with zeros, and for negative numbers, fill in with ones. This is called sign extension. The sign will not change.

Comment: If you find a carry bit when subtracting 00110 from any number of the form xxx11x, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Ahhh, but im not subtracting ;-). What i did was convert 001100 to 6-bit twos complement , and add. i.e. 110111+111010

Comment: You are still doing it wrong if you find a carry. xxx11x - 000110 is xxx00x and no carry. PS: 110111 is wrong, perhaps you are not applying “sign extension” correctly.

Comment: im sorry , but are you sure ? According to the text my teacher gave us, that is how you do sign-extension. And two complement sign-extension of 10111 is 110111 . Also , 00110 should become 000110. converting 000110 to twos complement : 111010. Now , 110111+111010 = 1110001. If i did this correctly , then of all the options , this is the closest to an overflow , because the result is 7 bits long. Isnt the extra '1' on the left a carry? i'm now learning.

Comment: Page 311 talks about sign extension , I just copied and pasted. http://electro.fisica.unlp.edu.ar/arq/downloads/Bibliografia/William%20Stallings%20-%20Computer%20Organization%20and%20Architecture%20Designing%20for%20Performance%20(8th%20Edition).pdf

Comment: is it possible that the answer is "none of them"?

Comment: THATS WHAT IM SAYING !!!! lol i think there is an error in the question. Either the answer is none of them , or its meant to be worked out as 5 bits , not 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On addition, the result may be larger than can be held in the word size
being used. This condition is called **overflow**.

In our case, we are using 6-bit arithmetic, so we can represent numbers from -32 (`100000`) up to + 31 (`011111`).

If two numbers are added in two's complement one is positive and the other one is negative, there will never be an overflow. The result will be a number within the range of the operands.

So according to your book, we have the *overflow rule*, on page 314.

> If two numbers are added, and they are both positive or both negative, then overflow occurs if and only if the result has the opposite sign.

So let's see all the items:

```
(a) carry-out but no overflow

  111001    -7
+ 001000    +8
  ------    --
 1000001    +1
```

```
(b) carry-out but no overflow

  110111     -9
+ 111000     -6
  ------    ---
 1101111    -17
```

Here we had to first use the subtraction rule, on page 315.

> To subtract one number (subtrahend) from another (minuend), take the twos complement (negation) of the subtrahend and add it to the minuend.

```
(c) no carry-out, no overflow

  000111     +7
+ 001100    +12
  ------    ---
  010011    +19
```

```
(d) no carry-out, no overflow

  110110    -10
+ 000011     +3
  ------    ---
  111001     -7
```

Note that, in `(a)` and `(b)`, there is a carry bit beyond the end of the word, which is ignored.

Comment: This is exactly my thinking. There has to be an error in the question. I guess we should be using five bits instead of 6